# PSR-4 autoloading not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, autoload, psr-4

I have created an `app/modules` directory and autoloaded it using PSR-4 like this:

```
"psr-4": {
    "Modules\\": "app/modules"
}
```

And I also did `composer dumpautoload`. I have the following directory structure:

```
app
- ...
- modules
-- ModuleName
--- controllers
---- BackendController.php
...
```

The file `BackendController.php` has the namespace `Modules\ModuleName\Controllers`.

And in `routes.php`, I have the following:

```
Route::resource('backend/modules/module-name', 'Modules\ModuleName\Controllers\BackendController');
```

But whenever I try to access 'backend/modules/module-name', I get a `ReflectionException` with the following message:

```
Class Modules\ModuleName\Controllers\BackendController does not exist
```

What may be causing the problem? When I run it in my local machine, it seems to work, but I can't get it to work on the webserver. Are there any server configuration scenarios, that may be causing this problem?

Since I don't have shell access to that webserver, I don't have composer installed on the webserver but it is installed on my local machine. I have uploaded all the files including `vendor` directory, to the server.

Comment: Try capitalizing the `controllers` folder to `Controllers`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [PSR-4 specification](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/):

> All class names MUST be referenced in a case-sensitive fashion.

So you'll need to rename your `modules` and `controllers` folders to `Modules` and `Controllers` respectively.

So it becomes:

```
app
- ...
- Modules
-- ModuleName
--- Controllers
---- BackendController.php
...
```

I wouldn't recommend renaming your namespaces to lowercase names because that just breaks the consistency in your code and project structure. It will be a headache to maintain and figure out which part of your namespace needs to be capitalized which one doesn't.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I forgot about the `case-sensitivity`.

Comment: I just realized that the spec says "class names". I have no idea if they intended to mean namespace names in the first place. But oh well, this is the closest clarification.

Answer (score 8):

You should look at capitalization.

Probably you test it on Windows machine so path

```
'Modules\ModuleName\Controllers\BackendController'
```

is the same as

```
'modules\ModuleName\controllers\BackendController'
```

But on Linux they are 2 different paths. You should probably change in your `routes.php` line from

```
Route::resource('backend/modules/module-name', 'Modules\ModuleName\Controllers\BackendController');
```

to

```
Route::resource('backend/modules/module-name', 'modules\ModuleName\controllers\BackendController');
```

Comment: That's what was wrong with my code and setup. I thought the autoloader would take care of that. I guess I was wrong. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I had the same issue but lower case paths actually *worked* in Linux - or SO I THOUGHT! It turned out I was testing inside a Vagrant box which mapped the paths out to my host OS X machine - which in turn uses case INsensitive filesystem. Caught it during production deploy :)

Comment: thanks for your comment...my problem solved...what a stupid mistake.... :(