# Php psr-4 Class not Found Error using Composer

Tags: php, composer-php, psr-4

I'm trying to exercise MVC concepts with php on "wamp-server"

At local directory i have the index.php page for basic routing with alto-router package and a routes.php file:

```
<?php
  $router->map('GET','/test', 'Acme\Controllers\PageController@test' ,'test');
```

[image: Folders]

composer.json file is:

```
{
    "name": "eren/eren",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Eren Ardahan",
            "email": "???@???.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "filp/whoops": "^1.1",
        "altorouter/altorouter": "1.1.0"

    },
    "autoload":{
      "psr-4":{"Acme\\":"src/"} 
    }
}
```

PageController.php is

```
<?php namespace Acme\Controllers;

use Acme\Testing\Test;

class PageController
{
  public function test(){
    include(__DIR__ . "/../../views/test.php");
    //---Deleted lines
    $test = new Test; 
    $test -> test();
    /---
  }

}
```

The Test.php in the acme directory is:

```
<?php namespace Acme\Testing;

class Test{
  public function test(){
    echo "Working";
  }
}
```

And The test.php in the view directory is above.And it works when i deleted the commented two lines in PageController.php

```
<?php
 echo "TEST PAGE <br>";
```

But with this lines there is an error :

Class 'Acme\Testing\Test' not found..

Comment: This is Windows/WAMP so maybe not a case-sensitivity issue (though case sensitivity is important to be aware of) but is the result the same if you rename those directories from `acme,controllers` to `Acme,Controllers`?  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24495987/psr-4-autoloading-not-working

Comment: Your namespace is wrong. It should be \Acme\acme because your test class is not inside the map Testing

Comment: @Micheal  Michael Berkowski i changed the directory names and then composer var dump-autoload..But class still not found.. The intersting thing in routes.php file i m using namespacing and it works

Comment: @Szenis is right..After i changed the acme directory name to Testing it worked..Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i said in the comment the problem is that the namespace is not correct.

I created this answer for people who might find this question in the future.

You have a directory called source wich has the namespace Acme. When u add another directory inside the source folder called acme the namespace will be:

```
Acme\acme
```

You will have to change the acme folder to Testing to get the right namespace.